# Confirmation Message Box Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have implemented the Google Apps Script code to show confirmation message, I am successful in showing the message using the Label but I am trying to display confirmation message in a box instead of the label so that it would be clear to user that they submitted the files successfully and can hit the OK button in that box. I tried achieving this goal using this code below but it shows following error message:

"Error encountered: SpreadsheetApp.getUi() can only be called from a script bound to the new
version of Google Sheets."

This is the new Google Spreadsheet I have created to code Google Apps Script, but I copied and pasted the existing code.

This is the code I tried to use to show confirmation message box (which is showing error message as listed above):

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var userChoice = ui.alert(
      'Thank You for uploading files',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);
   if (userChoice == ui.Button.OK) {
      ui.alert('Operation Confirmed.');
   } else {
      ui.alert('Operation Halted.');
   }
```

Below is the code that I am successful showing the confirmation message in label:

```
// Create form to hold the file upload buttons for choosing a file and uploading

var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);
  formContent.add(app.createLabel('All of the following files must be submitted prior to completing the form').setHeight('25px').setStyleAttributes(_lbl).setStyleAttribute('font-size','20px'));


  formContent.add(app.createLabel('Reference Letter').setHeight('20px').setStyleAttributes(_lbl));
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('Reference'));
  formContent.add(app.createLabel('Reference Letter 2').setHeight('20px').setStyleAttributes(_lbl));
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('Reference2'));
  formContent.add(app.createLabel('Reference Letter 3').setHeight('20px').setStyleAttributes(_lbl));
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('Reference3'));

formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit File Uploads'));

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.Reference;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.Reference2;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob2);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var fileBlob3 = e.parameter.Reference3;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob3);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  //Display a confirmation message
  var label = app.createLabel('Thank You for uploading files').setStyleAttribute('font-weight','bold').setStyleAttribute('font-size','1.1em');
  app.add(label);

  return app;

}
```

Is there any way to show confirmation message in box instead of in label? I have to show confirmation message for other part of the program also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DialogBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/dialog-box) or [PopupPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/popup-panel) instead of label. Check linked documentation for details.

On a side note, your doPost() function code sets `var app` three times, which is unnecessary. You might also want to edit your code to account for not all 3 files being selected and uploaded.

Comment: azawaza, Thank you so much for your answer. I applied PopupPanel as described in the documentation you listed above. PopupPanel is working but I did use string text inside popupPanel.setTag('Thank you for your application').setStyleAttribute('color', 'blue'); but my text is not showing up in popup. Any idea what I am missing. Your suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Popup panel is a panel, you can't write text in it directly, you should add a Label or an HTML widget to it and write your text in there.

Comment: Btw, a tag (on any UiApp widget) is actually an invisible field that one can use to transmit string data to the server functions. They are invisible by design.

Comment: Thanks Serge insas, your suggestion solved the issue of adding text to popupPanel. I used label to the popupPanel like this: popupPanel.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for your application');